# VsCode enter emoji in textfile

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I enter emojis in VsCode text editor?

In PowerShell I can enter the unicode endpoint via following escape code `` `u{1F600} ``.

I also tried the `Windows + .`  which shows me the emoji-picker. But VsCode is not able to render it:

[image]

The used font must be ok, since copy & paste of an emoji is working.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue with the extension `vscodevim` enabled.   
The emoji input works when I disable the extension on my setup.

Comment: @yhd.leung this was my exact problem.  there's a currently-open bug on the vim extension for poor surrogate pair handling code.  https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll note in this answer that `Windows + .` works perfectly on my computer for VSCode, so perhaps you may be making a mistake using it.

With that said, you can try using the Emojisense extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.emojisense